# Resource name must Start with a letter

Tags: android, build.gradle

I am having this issue when I am having file with name **01a.png** under `res/drawable`.

The error looks like:

```
Error: The resource name must start with a letter
```

I am using `build:gradle:2.1.2` and SDK version 24.

Any solution to fix this without changing filename and without degrading **SDK version**?

Comment: *Any solution to fix this without changing filename*. No, you have to change the filename. Btw it is not SDK version or gradle related. Downgrade won't help

Comment: this is not possible because android SDK does not support imagename which start with number,so make change the image name

Answer (score 2):

change the name of the resources, it MUST  start with a letter

Answer (score 1):

Imagname must starts with a letter so change the image name

Answer (score 1):

Resources are located on the left in your Android Studio. 
Project > app > res > values.. you'll find your resources there. Android studio will commonly mark the incorrect syntax with RED text

Answer (score 0):

In My Case when the **string key name** got removed from **string.xml** so I got this error,
for example:

```
<string name="">Submit Order</string>
```

after putting back string key name like below, it's working fine

```
<string name="label_submit_order">Submit Order</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did was change the resource names to icon_01a.png, then created a string to store the icon

```
String iconName = firstWeatherObject.getString("icon");
```

afterwards, I just added a "icon_" + iconName to call the image

```
int iconResourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("icon_"+iconName, "drawable", getPackageName());
```